# Design Pattern/Idea to refresh a row in a grid from what trigger would have done

Tags: c#, java, sql, sql-server, vb.net

So I have a table which has an INSERT/UPDATE trigger in SQL Server. When a user starts a new row in my DataGridView I would like to somehow get the values that the trigger would produce for all the fields if I had inserted the row? How have you done this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is to

```
<start transaction>
<insert row>
<read the row to get all values>
<rollback transaction>
```

This isn't pretty but this is the best I can think of at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Your going to have to get the default value for each column in your sql table...

execute a sql system query

`sp_columns <table_name>`

the column  `COLUMN_DEF` will have your default contraints

Comment: helpful, but what if my trigger executes something that changes a value in a column